# MS Access: Bound condition in endless Form via vba,

Tags: vba, ms-access

I just try to create a calendar in MS-Access out of 42 unbound Forms, using them as endless Listes of entrys.

Now I like to fill them with entrys of different typ (group-appointments, entrys from Joe or from Marry etc.) with a recordset, createt for every of this 42 forms. And in the end, all this entry shall have a specific color, so Joe will get his in blue and Marry some in red.

So first I fill the recordset of the Form and than I run threw it like this:

```
Dim objFormatConditionGroup As FormatCondition
Dim objFormatConditionJoe As FormatCondition
Dim objFormatConditionMarry As FormatCondition

Dim ctl As Control

With Me
  Do While Not .Recordset.EOF
    Set ctl = .Topic

    Set objFormatConditionGroup = ctl.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "'" & .Recordset.typ & "' = '1'")
    objFormatConditionGroup.BackColor = enmColor.Red
    objFormatConditionGroup.ForeColor = enmColor.White

    Set objFormatConditionJoe = ctl.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "'" & .Recordset.typ & "' = '2'")
    objFormatConditionJoe.BackColor = enmColor.Blue
    objFormatConditionJoe.ForeColor = enmColor.White

    Set objFormatConditionMarry = ctl.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "'" & .Recordset.typ & "' = '3")
    objFormatConditionMarry.BackColor = enmColor.White
    objFormatConditionMarry.ForeColor = enmColor.Black

    .Recordset.MoveNext
  Loop
End with
```

Works somehow, but if I have multiple entry in one List, I always get the style of the last used block in for all entrys. Like: If there is a Groupappointment an something from Marry in one day (entrys are sortet by recordset.Typ), all entrys appear in Marry-Styl.

I gues, there is something wrong in the conditions-part of FormatConditions, but I can not figure it out. It shout be a String, "1=1" and "0=1" work like expectet. But how can I refere to the recordset of only one entry in the List?

Or how can I change the control .Topic of just one entry in the List and not all of them in the same step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FormatConditions, you can't refer to VBA variables or values. You need to refer to the actual column from the form recordsource.

E.g.

```
ctl.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "[Typ] = '1'")
```

And don't do this in a recordset loop. Add each FormatCondition once. (As you have, but without the loop.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yep, that way it works stright as I would like to have it!